# How to calculate the "distance" between two rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, image-manipulation

Given one rectangle and a bunch of images (also rectangles), I need to find the best image to place in it. That would be the one that requires less stretching or shrinking and that covers the area the best. I want to find the one with the least distance (as in, least transformation) to the target rectangle. The images are screenshots of websites, so, they contain a mix of text and images. The screenshots suffer whether they are stretched (pixelation) or shrunk (text becomes unreadable).

But it also feels like one of these problems that someone might have looked into already and there might be an algorithm to properly solve it.

The data is stored in a SQL database so I would need the analysis to be doable in SQL. The data might look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Id                                   | Width | Height |  
---------------------------------------------------------
| 00b701c6-1c31-4323-a292-700b4dff2e45 |   784 |   1310 |
| 0a46a0f6-a3b2-4a5d-a8be-55bad84ba37d |  1414 |    957 |
| 0b79fbe8-6b9e-48d1-89da-8981570e23d7 |   784 |    561 |
| 0e9f5935-0e58-42d2-bba2-3e89db55260f |   400 |    400 |
| 0ebf14fb-094b-47f5-9e25-b4f54bc2eab9 |  2260 |    957 |
| 17131cd6-f5b2-4e4d-a63b-b909e04e2d89 |  1414 |    957 |
| 2298fc73-0bcb-49c8-b54e-3184cf4153d4 |   784 |   1310 |
| 28ffee4a-2d08-4862-aeb0-6546cda4e225 |  2560 |   1387 |
| 29cf92ad-b6fd-43c6-abb1-7c5a7e4af92d |  2260 |    957 |
| 307b2b6e-1f66-4784-bd7d-b6bfc4768fbd |  2560 |   1387 |
| 3edc916b-4b3d-4fd8-a1f9-6418a4d8d27a |  2333 |    435 |
| 3ef1132a-d059-487a-9cad-dbb3895ad25a |  1414 |    957 |
| 43e044e5-5f82-4b86-95ba-a9e76f5d2519 |   657 |    435 |
| 464be0ec-5cb7-4f3f-856d-6beb5fbc2f5e |   657 |    435 |
| 510d0236-e61a-4f1c-bb0b-754c4c1f80f7 |  2260 |    957 |
| 52f217d5-038c-475d-af96-89d1930e8c2f |   657 |    435 |
| 532cadf5-c20b-4b1c-84d4-78e1b501495f |  2333 |    435 |
| 5f3e55aa-12a4-4502-a159-fdc128b53e11 |  2260 |    957 |
| 626c33a9-aaa0-47b6-a6f3-bd5235f1655b |   784 |    561 |
| 6711a717-e1ee-4930-9f21-5e225a99a769 |   657 |    435 |
| 7125c301-c311-4339-b36c-519dc3714c68 |   784 |    561 |
| 8f5d8e3b-8213-4cd6-8ea0-311297f4cfc3 |  2333 |    435 |
| c3d7661f-12e6-4297-8830-15e82850bc32 |   784 |   1310 |
| cd32106e-2f3e-4614-ac40-19e3f5d7fa1f |   784 |    561 |
| d7191194-1f8a-4230-8ee0-8a8b427b86e7 |   784 |   1310 |
| d737de66-849d-4ec3-bf3b-cc48bfa1f3a6 |  2560 |   1387 |
| d935e10b-88f3-4aba-a2b4-a1a9cfd8acb4 |  2560 |   1387 |
| dcc8e9e6-4ee3-4737-a530-d2fcffd35a86 |  2333 |    435 |
| ec3187be-5a81-4ecb-a908-ddedaa5930ec |  1414 |    957 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Unclear what image placement has to do with distance between rectangles. Maybe edit the question title? Have you considered placing the rectangle over an image? And what are you trying to capture within the rectangle exactly? The entire image content, or some  important piece of it?

Comment: @cricket_007 one rectangle is the space for the image, the other is the potential image.

Comment: You probably want something like the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: I don't think you need distances. You want the difference in areas

Comment: Do you have example data (and how many candidates are there)?

Comment: @cricket_007: the different in area is only part of the problem. If there's a space of 1x2 and two images, 2x1, 1x1, the former has the perfect area, but the aspect ratio makes it a horrible candidate, the latter is a better candidate even though the difference in area is bigger.

Comment: @sascha: the data is very variable, I can produce some samples, but it wouldn't be anything else than a bunch of arbitrary pair of numbers. There can be thousands of candidates and it's on a SQL database with two columns, one of height and one for width.

Comment: Well it hasn't much value to act and compare approaches on those values alone (e.g. in regards to text-destruction). This is still too broad to act imho. I personally don't think the current answers are really approaching the complexity of the problem. For now i think you can skip convex-optimization approaches (maybe even *difference of convex-funcs*), also unconstrained nonlinear-programming seems not a good fit (at least smooth approaches), but constrained nonlinear-optimization might be a good cand. But this involves some coding and without a detailed goal people might be less motivated.

Comment: @sascha: there I added some sample data from my current development database. Most likely there will be a lot of records but not many different image sizes.

Comment: Content is still hidden (although the question made clear it matters), and more important: with hidden content, there is never any gain to not filter out dupes a-priori.

Comment: @sacha: what do you mean by content still hidden? There are no duplicate images but images of the same size.

Comment: I just added more details about the problem, specifically, the nature of the images.

Comment: Text, no Text, content of those images... what's unclear when you even mentioned the *text-problems*? If there would be an img with a big black rectangle on white background with the same ratio, i would just resize, even if it's by a factor of 0.01. But with text that's probably no good idea. If content is black-box and img_a has the same dimension as img_b: what do you think you are gaining by using whatever optimization on both candidates? The only difference is in data not used (content; not available). So in this case: filter out dupes of x=x && y=y.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) as follows:

```
function jaccard(rect : Rectangle, img : Rectangle) : float
  rectArea := rect.width * rect.height
  imgArea := img.width * img.height
  interArea := min(rect.width, img.width) * min(rect.height, img.height)
  return interArea / (rectArea + imgArea - interArea)
end
```

Then choose the highest scoring image (values go from zero to one).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete algorithm but my approach would be to score each image based on how good it matches the rectangle. The interesting parameter would the ratio (width/height), so calculate the ratio for each image and compare it to the ratio of the rectangle. The nearest ratio wins.

As for the second problem I'd probably set a threshold, if the ratio of the best fit is really close to the rectangle (below the threshold) you can get away with stretching (looks better than two very thin borders), if it's above the threshold add black borders since distorted text is hideous.